# SVG viewBox scales some elements differently than others

Tags: svg, snap.svg

The client asked to scale the drawing down so I added width/height and viewBox to the SVG element. The problem is that some elements are scaled differently than others. The structure of the svg is like this:

`<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 50 700 200">
    <defs>...</defs>
    <g id="group-ab">
        Here are the boxes (drawn with polyline) that are scaled correctly, both in their own group (group-a, group-b)
    </g>
    <g id="group-a-id">
        <text>A</text>
        <circle id="group-a-id-bg-circle"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="group-B-id">
        <text>B</text>
        <circle id="group-b-id-bg-circle"></circle>
    </g>
    <path id="group-a-pattern" d="..."></path>
    <path id="group-b-pattern" d="..."></path>
</svg>`

The path is the pattern for the pieces. It seems that everything that isn't under the group "group-ab" isn't scaled correctly, see the image below. Normally (when not using viewBox) the pattern fills up the boxes and the A/B are centered with the boxes (same translates are done to them).

[image]

Why is this happening? One would think that it doesn't matter if elements are within groups or not if svg is scaled.

Comment: Is it possible to post a jsfiddle of it ?